# Does throttle control altitude and yoke control airspeed?

Tags: flight-controls, throttle

I read that Throttle controls altitude and control wheel/ stick controls airspeed. Is that true? if so please explain.

Comment: you should read [how it flies](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/energy.html#sec-conv-fuel-alt). engines add energy that is used for improving both kinetic and potential energy

Comment: I was taught this, but I was taught it as a specific *technique* for a specific phase of flight (approach). Not as an aerodynamic principle.